# DBD::mysql: How can I write with "SELECT * INTO file" to my home-directory?

Tags: mysql, perl

is there a way to make this work?
(write the out_file to my home-directory)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Spec::Functions;
use File::HomeDir;
use DBI;

my $database = 'my_db';
my $table = 'my_table';
my $user = 'user';
my $passwd = 'password';

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:$database;", 
$user, $passwd, { RaiseError=>1, AutoCommit=>1 } );

$dbh->do( qq{ DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table } );
$dbh->do( qq{ CREATE TABLE $table (
    artikel INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    haendler  CHAR(20) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    preis   DOUBLE(16,2) DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( artikel, haendler ) ); } );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( qq{ INSERT INTO $table 
    ( artikel, haendler, preis ) 
    VALUES( ?, ?, ? ) } );

$sth->execute( 1, 'Dotter', 1.35 );
$sth->execute( 2, 'Kahlo', 2.00 );
$sth->execute( 3, 'Schmidt', 4.30 );
$sth->execute( 3, 'Kahlo', 4.45 );


my $out_file = 'out_file.csv';
my $home_dir = File::HomeDir->my_documents;
$out_file = catfile $home_dir, $out_file;

$dbh->do( qq{ SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$out_file' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    FROM $table; } );

# DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create/write to file '/home/user/out_file.csv' (Errcode: 13) at ./mysql.pl line 44.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> # DBD::mysql::db do failed: Can't create/write to file '/home/user/out_file.csv' (Errcode: 13) at ./mysql.pl line 44.

That error message is totally dumb, how typical of MySQL. This code number is not platform portable. (POSIX specifies only the symbol names, not the numbers!)

Software that is not programmed by total amateurs uses the `strerror` system call to provide a descriptive and localisable error message.

I had to dive into `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` in order to look up the number; I here just assume you use Linux, too:

`#define      EACCES          13      /* Permission denied */`

So there you have it, dangerstat guessed correctly.

Comment: I run the script as user “mike” and I connect to the database also as user “mike” and “print $home_dir” gives me “/home/mike” so I don’t know where I should change permissions.

Comment: Your database process runs as a different user. `ps`, `htop` or similar tools can easily show you. You would need to adapt permissions on at least your home directory. I cannot teach you about Unix permissions and what this means for security in this short comment, I suggest you learn about it from a good book or the local Linux user group.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the script as a user that has permissions to write to that directory?

(ops sorry I meant to write this as a comment :/ I fail)

Comment: I run the script as user “mike” and I connect to the database also as user “mike” and “print $home_dir” gives me “/home/mike” so I don’t know where I should change permissions.